# Declaring multiple variables in single line + Angular 2 & TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Coming from Java background and taking toddler steps in Angular 2 with TypeScript, gives scope for so many comparisons. We can declare variables with types `name : string` inside a class in Angular 2 / TypeScript. How do i declare multiple variables of same type in single shot ? Is there a way to declare like `name, designation, email : string` in single line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no syntax** that would work as just writing the type for each variable individually.

Comment: Tried couple of options but failed. Declaring each variable in separate line is such a pain !